# How do I loop through a SimpleXML object in PHP

Tags: php, simplexml

I have a simpleXml object and want to read the data from the object , I am new to PHP and dont quite know how to do this. The object details are as follows.

I need to read [description] and [hours]. Thankyou.

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [@attributes] => Array (
        [type] => array
    )
    [time-entry] => Array (
        [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
            [date] => 2010-01-26
            [description] => TCDM1 data management: sort & upload
            [hours] => 1.0
            [id] => 21753865
            [person-id] => 350501
            [project-id] => 4287373
            [todo-item-id] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                [@attributes] => Array (
                    [type] => integer
                    [nil] => true
                )
            )
        )
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
            [date] => 2010-01-27
            [description] => PDCH1: HTML
            [hours] => 0.25
            [id] => 21782012
            [person-id] => 1828493
            [project-id] => 4249185
            [todo-item-id] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
                [@attributes] => Array (
                    [type] => integer
                    [nil] => true
                )
            )
)   )   )
```

Please help me. I tries a lot of stuff , but not getting the syntax right.

Answer (score 10):

It's really hard to read the above, if you could give us a screen shot or give line spacing and indents, that would be a bit better
If you have an object

$xml that is a simplexml object, you can access elements like

```
$xml->element.
```

It looks like is an element of time entry, in which case you would loop through like this:

```
foreach( $xml->{'time-entry'} as $time_entry ) {
    echo $time_entry->description . "<br />\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the object that you `print_r`-ed in the question is in `$element` then the following will loop over the two `time-entry` elements while printing out their respective `description` and `hours` values.

```
foreach ($element->{'time-entry'} as $entry) {
    $description = (string) $entry->description;
    $hours       = (string) $entry->hours;
    printf("Description: %s\nHours: %s\n\n", $description, $hours);
}
```

Outputs something like:

```
Description: TCDM1 data management: sort & upload NFP SubProducers list
Hours: 1.0

Description: PDCH1: HTML
Hours: 0.25
```

Note that the `time-entry` element name has to be wrapped in curly braces<sup>1</sup> as a string since otherwise `$element->time-entry` would try to read the `time` element and subtract the value of a constant called `entry` which is obviously not what we want.  Also, the `description` and `hours` values are cast<sup>2</sup> to strings (they would otherwise be objects of type `SimpleXMLElement`).

<sup>1. See [variable variables](http://php.net/variables.variable)</sup>
<sup>2. See [type casting](http://php.net/types.type-juggling#language.types.typecasting)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am new to PHP I just started learning so my concepts come from C programming. I might be doing an excessive amount of work/coding here... but I'm sure I'll get yelled at by someone and learn.

This returns an array back which is nicely laid out for accessing all the individual bits of data without having to handle SimpleXMLElement objects:

```
public $xmlFileInName = 'sample.xml';

public $errorMessage = "Failed to open file: ";

public function actionGetArray()
{
    try {
        $xml = file_exists($this->xmlFileInName) ?
        simplexml_load_file($this->xmlFileInName) :
        exit($this->errorMessage. $this->xmlFileInName);

        $xmlArray=$this->arrayFromSxe ($xml);

        echo var_dump($xmlArray);
    }
    catch(Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}

public function arrayFromSxe($sxe)
{
    $returnArray = array();
    foreach ((array)$sxe as $key=>$value) {
        if(is_array($value) && !$this->is_assoc($value)) {
            $indies = array();
            foreach($value as $secondkey=>$secondvalue)
                $indies[$secondkey] = $this->arrayFromSxe($secondvalue);
            $returnArray[$key] = $indies;
        }
        else {
            if(is_object($value)) {
                $returnArray[$key] = $this->arrayFromSxe($value);
            } else {
                $returnArray[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }
    return $returnArray;
}

function is_assoc($array) {
    return (bool)count(array_filter(array_keys($array), 'is_string'));
}
```

Note that with multiple xml tags, i.e. in your example:

```
[time-entry] => Array (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    ...
    )
    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
    ...
    )
```

You will have to know something about the structure of the XML file in order to address this in you code. 
This will return in an array after calling this line:

```
$xmlArray=$this->arrayFromSxe ($xml);
```

Which will have:

```
[time-entry][0]
[time-entry][1]
```

So your code will need to know to iterate over all time-entries via int indexers or in any situation which their are multiple occurrences of an xml element.

If what I have said doesn't make sense then disregard it and simply observe and evaluate the code as it stands.

Hope this helps.